# Is it on topic for a question to ask for a canonical example?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I want to ask a question with the title **Is there a canonical example demonstrating the difference between predictive and explanatory models?**

I have ideas about the body of this question, with some references, but have not yet written it, although I think the title gets at the meat of it. However, I notice that we have neither an `[example]` tag, nor a `[pedagogy]` tag which makes me wonder if this kind of question might be appropriate, or if it would be too broad or too subjective a question.

PS I would welcome references which you think might be useful for me to look at on the topic of my intended question posted as comments. :)

Comment: It would certainly be on-topic to have a question about the difference between them and give your hopefully canonical answer but I sense you have something else in mind?

Comment: Be aware that there are a number of existing threads on this issue, so your question may be a duplicate (eg, [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1194/7290), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/269625/), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/409094/), [4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/108709/), etc).

Comment: When I first read the title, I figured this would be about questions seeking a tutorial, which (for better or worse) isn't something we do. Your specific question elaborated in the text is different from that. But a concern would be how could you choose which is the 'right answer' from several such posted examples? If you're not asking for code, you're not asking for a tutorial; your Q isn't a duplicate, & it's easy to see how a particular response is the correct answer, I don't see any reason such a question should be closed.

Comment: @gung Thank you for the links. While all of these discuss prediction vs explanation, *none* of these provide *model examples*, which would be a primary motivation driving my question.

Comment: @gung "how could you choose which is the 'right answer' from several such posted examples?" From my dictionary, 3rd definition of 'canonical': "reduced to the simplest and most significant form possible without loss of generality". There might *not* be such an answer. One the other hand, there might be: if I were to ask for a canonical example of a measure of data centrality, I could see acceptable answers using the mean, median or both.